# Four mutually exhaustive sets; finding the intersection of two sets. Set theory and system of equations.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, systems-of-equations

In a group of 120 persons there are 80 elements of B and 40 elements of G. Further 70 persons in the group are M and the remaining are H. Then the number of elements that are both in B as well as M.

I have made the following approach:

[image]

Let BM be the elements of B which are also in M; similarly for all the combinations.

Now can we write:

BM + BH = 80
GM + GH = 40

MB + MG = 70
HB + HG = 50
We need to find BM.

Which further brings us to the following system of equations:

a + b =50
c + d =70
c + a =80
d + b =40

This is where I am stuck. I find it fairly impossible to find any solution from the above equations. ( I tried calculating the row echelon form of the matrix, with disastrous results) This makes me doubt the correctness of my approach.

Maybe a kind soul could give me a heads up.

There has been some talk about incomplete information so I am going to cut the crap and attach the original question:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t enough information to answer the question. To see this, note that both of the following arrangements are possible (among many others), and one has $70$ people in $B\cap M$, while the other has only $30$.

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
&B&G&\text{Total}\\ \hline
M&70&0&70\\
H&10&40&50\\ \hline
\text{Total}&80&40&120
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
&B&G&\text{Total}\\ \hline
M&30&40&70\\
H&50&0&50\\ \hline
\text{Total}&80&40&120
\end{array}$$

**Added:** Now that we know that it’s a multiple choice question, the situation is a little different. The arrangements above show that the only choice that could possibly be correct is (A), and we can prove without much difficulty that (A) *is* correct: if $|B\cap M|<30$, then $|B\cap H|>50$, which is impossible, since there are only $50$ Hindus. Thus, we must certainly have $|B\cap M|\ge 30$.

Comment: But this is all that is given :(

Comment: Is this a ratio proportion sum?

Comment: @swarm: If this is really all that is given, the question is bad: it cannot be answered.

Comment: can it be solved now with the original text?

Comment: @swarm: Yes. The two sample arrangements show that the only choice that could possibly be right is (A), and we can prove that (A) *is* correct. If $|B\cap M|<30$, then $|B\cap H|>50$, which is impossible, since there are only $50$ Hindus.